# DataGrid control enable in DIV runtime

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have 2 button in ASP.net, when i pressed button1 my div innerhtml changed to some value. and when I press the button2 my datagrid will display in the same div.

Please tell me how can i display the datagrid inside the div at runtime.

Thanks,
Manoj Singhal

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the `Visible` property of your Datagrid from button2.